# React Testing: How to test useState and boolean if Statements in React

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to test a simple if statement but not sure how to go about it.
Here's the component:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);

const exitToast = (isOpen: boolean) =>
 isOpen ? setOpen(false) : setOpen(true);

return(
<div>
 <Toast
   label={<span>Incorrect Info</span>}
   isOpen={open}
   type='error'
   closeIcon
   onClose={() => closeTost(true)}
  />
</div>
)
```

Here's my Tests:

THIS TEST IS PASSING (**but I don't think it's a good test.**)

```
test('Should not show text "Incorrect Info" when isOpen is true', () => {
 render(<MyComp />)
 const toastWrapper = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true)
  return setOpen(false)
 }
 expect(screen.queryByLabelText('Incorrect Info')).not.beInTheDocument()
})
```

THIS TEST IS **NOT** PASSING

```
test('Should show text "Incorrect Info" when isOpen is false', () => {
 render(<MyComp />)
 const toastWrapper = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true)
  return setOpen(true)
 }
 expect(screen.queryByLabelText('Incorrect Info')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Any help on this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test React. Instead of that you should test the UI.

```
test('Should render something when clicked', () => {
 // render component
 render(<MyComp />)
 
 // get button to do something
 const openButton = screen.getByTestId('open-button');

 // simulate click on it
 fireEvent.click(openButton)
 
 // test that something happen after the click
 expect(screen.queryByLabelText('Some text')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```